# How to set two scrollable view

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview, storyboard

I want to work with to view, when we push on a button of the first view we go on the second view by hiding the first view.

The 2 views have different heights... So heres my hierarchy:

-> Main View

-> -> Scroll View

-> -> -> Ui View 1

-> -> -> Ui View 2

How can I set the constraints in this configuration only by using the storyboard please ?

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a picture of your storyboard so we can figure out how it looks?

Comment: What about using a collectionView?

Comment: @RyanM just adde a picture

Comment: @AhmadF never used it im gonna do some searches

Comment: You can do it with constraints, which I did myself before I learned the wonders of stack views. Use a vertical stack view inside the scroll view.

Comment: I believe that using a collectionView should be a better solution for your case :)